# Migrating MongoDB Auth code to Mysql Node.Js

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, mongodb, passport.js

I am trying to achieve Oauth2 authentication and I came across a GitHub Repo which fits my description but the database used is MongoDB and I want to use MySql.

I want to convert this code of MongoDB Authentication to MySQL

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/MyDatabase');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserDetail = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});
const UserDetails = mongoose.model('userInfo', UserDetail, 'userInfo');
```

I have written this much code till now

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection   = mysql.createConnection({
supportBigNumbers: true,
bigNumberStrings: true,
host     : "localhost",
user     : "root",
password : "root",
database : "db_users"
});
```

Please refer the following GitHub repo for full code
https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/LocalPassportAuth
What should I add in this code to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I had great success answering this question using the following NPM package

https://github.com/aponica/mysqlgoose-js

It saved me allot of time migrating my NodeJS authentication API's to using MySQL as my back-end database instead of using MongoDB after my free mLabs account was deactivated and MongoDB was forcing me to a paid plan.

The steps for me were

1. Create all MySql tables using my MongoDb models as a template
2. Create a mysql.json connection file allowing a connection from NodeJS to MySql
3. Use the NPX Import tool to create a definitions JSON file of my MySQL schema that I load at runtime in NodeJS
4. Build a promise-based initialization function in my routes that connects with MySql and loads the defs tile to perform mongoose-like operations on my MySql tables
5. Make sure to close the MySQL connection upon sending a response from my API

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to add the connection in a separate file. 
After this what are your main issue ? Because the mysql code is correct for a connection.

With `connection.connect()` it's now working.

Comment: I have the added the connection code in separate file but it is still not working